# create-metadata-templ in ssoadm/OpenAM fails

Tags: metadata, single-sign-on, openam

I'm trying to create metadata template using ssoadm in OpenAM with the following command:

```
ssoadm create-metadata-templ -u amadmin -f pwd.txt -m sp.xml -x sp-extended.xml -s /sp -a -y https://stage1.abc.xyz.com/OpenAM
```

It gives the following error:

```
Incorrect option(s), ssoadm  create-metadata-templ -u amadmin -f pwd.txt -m sp.xml -x sp-extended.xml -s /sp -a -y https://stage1.agileworkbe
nch.accenture.com/OpenAM.


ssoadm create-metadata-templ --options [--global-options]
    Create new metadata template.

Usage:
ssoadm create-metadata-templ
    --entityid|-y
    --adminid|-u
    --password-file|-f
    [--meta-data-file|-m]
    [--extended-data-file|-x]
    [--serviceprovider|-s]
    [--identityprovider|-i]
    [--attrqueryprovider|-S]
    [--attrauthority|-I]
    [--authnauthority|-C]
    [--xacmlpep|-e]
    [--xacmlpdp|-p]
    [--affiliation|-F]
    [--affiownerid|-N]
...
...
....
......
```

I use OpenAM 12.0.0 in Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise deployed in Tomcat 7/Java 7.

Any help is highly appreciated.

-Aravind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `-y` (which is mandatory for the command) is treated as a value for `-a` key.

You should provide a value for `-a` key or remove the key from the command.